# How can I run a Task Scheduler job without being on administrator account?

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks, task-scheduler

I have read that the Windows account logged onto the computer that is running tasks from the Windows Task Scheduler needs to have administrator rights. I used the administrator account to create the task, but the problem is I cannot leave the computer with the admin account logged on. I have to switch to the non-admin account, but I want that task to still be run based on the criteria I have set up within Task Scheduler.

Is there any way where I can setup a task in Task Scheduler and have it run on an account that doesn't have administrator rights?

PS: The task is a very simple one. Moving files from one place to another, that's all.

Comment: @turmuka: This is a very old post, and its description is very bad. You must tell us what's wrong with the existing answer, whether the task was defined in the Task Scheduler and which account.

Comment: basically the question is, can I create a task without the Administrator account (no admin rights) @harrymc

Comment: @turmuka: Is the task to be run with the highest privileges (admin)? If it's not, do you want it to be *created by an admin* and then triggered by a non-admin?

Comment: no, just create by a non admin user, trigger by a non admin user @harrymc

Comment: @turmuka: I have added an answer for a standard user.

Comment: It’s been a while since I asked this question. IIRC, my hope was for there to have something where I can increase the scope of permissions for a standard user. It turns out that it isn’t possible. Until there is a direct solution to this issue, I will mark @harrymc suggestion as answer for now as it does seem like it has the most details. Thanks!

Comment: You can't create Task Scheduler tasks without Administrator privileges, however there can be circumventions, you can use many third party softwares that can elevate a program to not only Administrator but also TrustedInstaller, examples include PsExec, PowerRun and NSudo, you can then possibly create scheduled tasks with elevated taskschd.msc, however I never used an account with only User privileges so I don't know if such tools will work without Administrator rights, and I had never actually tried it, so this is a guess.

Comment: @XeнεiΞэnвϵς: PsExec etc. need administrator permissions/account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to create a scheduled task without admin rights,
or this would be a serious security bug in Windows.

The Task Scheduler can only be used by an administrator, so you should look for some
other solution for a standard user, by using a third-party product.

Here is a list of scheduling products that do not use the Task Scheduler,
in no particular order. Some are pretty basic and some are more complex.
I haven't used them, so cannot recommend one in particular.

- [Z-Cron Scheduler](https://www.z-cron.com/index.html)
- [System Scheduler Free](https://www.splinterware.com/products/scheduler.html)
- [Task Till Dawn](https://www.oliver-matuschin.de/en/projects/task-till-dawn)
- [RoboIntern](https://robointern.tech/)
- [Solway’s Task Scheduler](http://www.theabsolute.net/sware/#tasksched)
- [Kana Reminder](https://kanasolution.com/products/kana-reminder/)

Comment: The way this answer is written, it's not quite correct (at least as of windows 10 in 2023). If a non-admin user wants to schedule a task, that runs only while that non-admin user is logged in, and the task itself doesn't require admin rights, of course it's possible to do that.

Comment: @DrPhil: You're right, of course. This answer was specific to the user's case.

Comment: You can absolutely create a tasks without admin rights, it's just local to your standard user account. You can run task scheduler without any admin rights whatsoever, you will just be prompted for credentials during task creation if you pick task settings that requires UAC premissions.

Answer (score 2):

@xenon if you have admin access, created a scheduled task, & only works while admin is logged in sounds like the task and/or script needs to be fixed. Ideas:

- Check that task is setup to run when admin user logged out:
  [image]
- Does the task/script require some kind of interaction, if so remove or automate it
- If task doesn't require admin access follow steps below to put in non-admin user startup
- Worst method: if task requires admin & you can't automate it for some reason (requires user interaction): create shortcut of batch script, modify shortcut to open as admin (will prompt for password every time its opened), place shortcut in non-admin user startup location seen below
  [image]

@turmuka run automated task for non-admin user: don't use Task Scheduler, write batch script, put in user startup so it runs automatically.

1. [Write a batch script (.BAT or .CMD)](https://www.howtogeek.com/263177/how-to-write-a-batch-script-on-windows/)
2. Test it
3. Put in User Startup: run, `shell:startup`, paste batch script or shortcut to batch script here

`C:\Users\InsertUsernameHere\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely create a service account with Administrator privileges and set it to run the job when Windows start up.

1. Create New Task
2. General --> Security Options:

- Run whether user is logged on or not
- Run with highest privileges.
- When running the task, use the following user account --> Set to service account.

3. Define Actions and triggers and condition, the click OK
4. Password requested for account, please key in password.
5. Setup is completed.

Answer (score 0):

Which steps are you taking when you create a task using Windows Task Scheduler? In the very first window, General tab, you can change the user the task should run for, and check the "Run with highest privileges" box.

Create the task with your admin account and it should work just fine for the other account.